# Is there a 64-bit Windows 7 driver for a Logitech Wingman Formula Force wheel?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, logitech-gamepad

I've used my Logitech Wingman Formula Force wheel for more years than I can remember (I definitely had it back when I was playing Viper Racing, though).  Sadly, Logitech does not appear to support the wheel in any capacity, even as an analog input device.

At this point, I'm looking for any sort of driver that will take input from the device.  I don't care at all about the force feedback but, if it were available, I'd be happy to take it.  The target operating system is Windows 7 64-bit.

EDIT: Just in case I'm not clear above: I know where the standard driver download sites are and have tried them out.  The problem is that Logitech has officially end-of-lifed this wheel so their latest software specifically does not support it.  Sadly, their older software that does support it is 32-bit only so I'm out of luck on that front.

Comment: Have you tried to install the drivers in Vista x32 compatibility mode?

Comment: Yes, the software specifically does not support the old wheel.

Comment: @Robotnik, except that mine came out two years before that one.  The duplication can go the other way, though.

Comment: @Bob - the other one has a better (non-link-only), higher-voted answer, and about-equal views despite being two years younger. I took the age into consideration when flagging the duplicate, but decided to flag in favour of the (IMHO) better answer

Comment: Which is in accordance with [this meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6924/should-older-questions-be-flagged-as-duplicates-of-more-recent-ones-if-those-hav)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [these 64-bit drivers](http://www.logitech.com/pub/techsupport/joystick/lgs502_x64.exe)?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same wheel, but try out the drivers for [Logitech MOMO](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/441/320&cl=us,en?osid=14). Else have a look at [this link](http://download.cnet.com/Logitech-WingMan-Formula-Force-USB/3000-18490_4-65008.html) as well

Comment: Sadly, that's exactly what I mean: the new software specifically does not support the old wheel.  Likewise, the old driver does not work with Windows 7 64 bit.  Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: Oh. I can't find the drivers, you can try out a tool like DriverMax( http://www.innovative-sol.com/drivermax/ ). Worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use this 32-bits driver in XP Mode, but not in 64-bits mode.

Comment: Yes, in a virtual machine running Windows XP, I'm pretty sure that the driver would continue to work.  However, I'm running without virtual machines.  The goal is to have a straightforward machine that just works.  This is the only device on my shelf that's currently causing trouble so I don't want to add the hassle of a virtual machine just for it.